# Require a view and add with a variable (Appcelerator Alloy)

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I do not know if I am doing it right or using any good practices, but I am trying to require and add views on my view.

but here I have a view container in my index.xml

```
<View id="containerDays" layout="vertical" height="Titanium.UI.SIZE">
    <Require id="requiredDay" src="NewDay"/>
</View>
<Label id="buttonAddDay"  class="button" >Adicionar outro dia</Label>
```

also on the index.js I have:

```
$.buttonAddDay.addEventListener("click", addNewDay);
function addNewDay () {
  var novoDia  = $.getView("NewDay");
  $.containerDays.add(novoDia);
}
```

also I have the view here in another folder on:

```
/app/views/NewDay.xml
```

and inside that view is a simple input

```
<Alloy>
  <View class="containerNewDay" layout="vertical" height="Titanium.UI.SIZE">
    <TextField id="Day" >write a new day</TextField>
  </View>
</Alloy>
```

so summing everything up,

1. I am trying to add my $.containerNewDay inside my $.containerDay, but I am not having any success with the getView() or the .open()
2. I will have to use all the textfield items to send it to a server, how can I set the ids but unfortunately I have no Idea how to do that on appcelerator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re the answer above, are you including the .add method from your original block of code? so it should be:

```
$.buttonAddDay.addEventListener("click", addNewDay);

function addNewDay () {
  var novoDia  = Alloy.createController("NewDay").getView();
  $.containerDays.add(novoDia);
}
```

or better, would be:

```
function addNewDay () {
  $.containerDays.add(Alloy.createController("NewDay").getView());
}
```

as this doesn't leave a pointer open to the view.

if you wanted to make it even cleaner:

```
$.buttonAddDay.addEventListener("click",  function addNewDay () {
  $.containerDays.add(Alloy.createController("NewDay").getView());
});
```

or if you want to stick to a "pure" Alloy way, then leave the **addNewDay** function in place and just add an **onClick="addNewDay"** handler in the button XML.

Crucially, remember that you'll need your containing view **ContainerDays** to have a layout of **horizontal** or your added views will simply sit on-top of each other.

Comment: IT solved my problem 1, the second problem of getting the value of each newDay I still don't have a clue.

Comment: Re 2 -- if you're after getting the value of the textfield, you could modify the add function so you create a pointer to the NewDay controller, then store an array of pointers to the textfields so push each textfield to the array -- at the end you'll have an array you could iterate through

Comment: Another option for 2. is to iterate the children of $.containerDays and then get the first child of each result (which would be the textfield).

Comment: finally, you could implement a solution that uses the blur event of the text fields to store the textfield value somewhere -- where you can retrieve it on save -- there's various options.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$.buttonAddDay.addEventListener("click", addNewDay);
    function addNewDay () {
      var novoDia  = $.getView("NewDay");
    }
```

To:

```
$.buttonAddDay.addEventListener("click", addNewDay);
function addNewDay () {
  var novoDia  = Alloy.createController("NewDay").getView();
}
```

Comment: hi, it didn't work for me, I edited my post and added a line on that function 
function addNewDay () {
  var novoDia  = Alloy.createController("NewDay").getView();
  $.containerDays.add(novoDia);
}

Comment: nothing happened and no error, the container ($.containerDays) does not have a $.novodia inside it..

Comment: also I am using the 5.1.2GA